# host_vars and group_vars are not getting loaded

Tags: vagrant, ansible, vagrantfile, ansible-inventory

I have below folder structure, which seem to make it build and load the roles, but the group and host vars are not being loaded. How come?

**/etc/ansible/**

```
- hosts
- requirements.yml
- group_vars/
    - app/
        - postgres.yml
- host_vars/
    - app1/
        - postgres.yml
- roles
```

**/documents/ansible/**

```
- playbook.yml
- vagrant
```

**host file**

```
# Application servers
[app]
192.168.60.6

# Group multi 
[multi:children]
app


#variables applied to all servers
[multi:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=vagrant
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

**vagrant **

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :


Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  # Genral Vagrant VM Configuration.
  config.vm.box = "geerlingguy/centos7"
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
    v.memory = 256
    v.linked_clone = true
  end

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
  end

# Application server 1
config.vm.define "app1" do |app|
  app.vm.hostname = "orc-app1.dev"
  app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.6"
end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vagrant by default uses its own, auto-generated inventory file in `.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory`.

There is an option `ansible.inventory_path` in Vagrant to point to the inventory file/directory other than the auto-generated one, but you don't use it to point to the `/etc/ansible/hosts` in `Vagrantfile`, so Vagrant is completely unaware of it. Likewise it does not look for `host_vars` and `group_vars` in the `/etc/ansible`.

---

On the other hand, the path to roles is not overridden by the inventory file, so the fact that Vagrant uses its own one does not influence the path for roles.

They are loaded by default from `/etc/ansible/roles` (or whatever directory Ansible uses as its default, for example `/usr/local/etc/ansible/roles` on macOS).

Comment: So i need to copy the `host_vars` and `group_vars`to playbook.yml folder? and how do i point to `/etc/ansible/hosts`in vagrant file?

Comment: I don't know what you need, because I don't know what you want. On a first glance, it makes no sense to use a global inventory file for a Vagrant project, but maybe you have your own reasons. I'm not sure about the second question either, I have given the name of the setting in the answer - what is the problem with just using it?

Comment: And even if you copy `group_vars` as is, Vagrant will have no clue what `app` is. It will source the `app1` from `host_vars`, because you define `app1` in the `Vagrantfile` and it will be reflected in the auto-generated inventory, but not `app`.

Comment: i see, however i just thought that since i specified groups in hosts file it would know

Comment: So you need to use the option I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me; it's a combo of various advice found on this and other sites,

### Solution

In my Vagrantfile (esp. note the `ansible.groups` line),

```
 config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
  ansible.playbook = "provisioning/site.yml"
  # "default" is the name of the VM as in auto-generated
  ansible.groups = { "vagrant" => ["default"] }
end
```

My inventory data for the VM goes in `provisioning/host_vars/default` and/or `provisioning/group_vars/vagrant` - either as files or directories with files (I prefer this so I can have a file for each role I'm using). Ensure these inventory files have a meaningful extension (so `.yml` assuming YAML format files) thus `provisioning/host_vars/default/role_name.yml` or `provisioning/group_vars/vagrant/role_name.yml`. `provisioning` can be a directory or (my preference) a symlink; the latter means I can have a common set of roles for my vagrant-handled VMs. *Gotcha: Using filename extensions is important; I notice that inventory data that I used to have in files without extensions is now ignored, so I think this is a change in how Ansible reads its inventory.*

### Background details

The `ansible.groups` setting in the `Vagrantfile` tweaks the auto-generated inventory in `.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory` mentioned in @techraf's answer to add,

```
[vagrant]
default
```

The line in the Vagrantfile shown above,

```
  ansible.playbook = "provisioning/site.yml"
```

not only specifies the playbook, but also means the playbook directory (or symlink to a directory) is `provisioning/`.

Vagrant looks in `provisioning/host_vars` etc because "You can also add `group_vars/` and `host_vars/` directories to your playbook directory." (from this [inventory documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables))

For clarity, here are the contents of each vagrant VM directory,

```
.vagrant/
ansible.cfg
provisioning -> shared_playbook_directory
Vagrantfile
```

and in the shared playbook directory,

```
group_vars/
host_vars/
roles/
site.yml
```

FYI [this Ansible & Vagrant intro page](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_intro) details the `host_vars`, `group_vars` etc. inventory layout very well.